# Promise.all returning promise for array of promises, but returning correct value for single promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise

I am using Promise for Readfile from storage and convert to base64 string.
I have array of images,using RNFS for read images

```
const promise_Images = _Images.map(async (nOPImg) => {

                    //get base 64 image
                    let image = await RNFS.readFile(nOPImg.photourl, 'base64')
                    nOPImg.photo = image

                   return nOPImg
                }

        })

const promise_Images2 = _Images.map(async (nOPImg) => {

                    //get base 64 image
                    let image = await RNFS.readFile(nOPImg.photourl, 'base64')
                    nOPImg.photo = image

                   return nOPImg
                }

        })
```

Now if I use promise all just with single promise returning correct out put

```
Promise.all(promise_Images ).then(res => {
                console.log("Image List", res)

                })
```

But if I execute all the promises at once it returning promise

```
 Promise.all(promise_Images1, promise_Images2  ).then(res => {
                console.log("Image List", res)

                })
```

result

```
0: Promise {_40: 1, _65: 1, _55: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SER…RQAUUUUAFFFFABQKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA//Z", _72: null}
1: Promise {_40: 1, _65: 1, _55: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SER…FFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAf/Z", _72: null}
2: Promise {_40: 1, _65: 1, _55: undefined, _72: null}
3: Promise {_40: 1, _65: 1, _55: undefined, _72: null}
```

How can I just return base64 string here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if i execute all the promises at one it returning promise

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) accepts **one** parameter: An array of the promises it should work with. You're passing it two arguments. It ignores the second one.

If `promise_Images1` and `promise_Images2` are both arrays, combine them:

```
Promise.all([...promise_Images1, ...promise_Images2]).then(res => {
    // ...
})
```

Comment: This is working perfectly.but can i know what is the difference between these two functions Promise.all([...promise_Images1, ...promise_Images2]).then(res => { // ... }) and Promise.all([promise_Images1, promise_Images2]).then(res => { // ... }) Thank you.

Comment: @Sk. - `[...promise_Images1, ...promise_Images2]` creates an array containing all of the entries from `promise_Images1` and `promise_Images2`.  `[promise_Images1, promise_Images2]` creates an array with two entries: The array `promise_Images1` and the array `promise_Images2`. (Similar to a two-dimensional array,) `Promise.all` won't wait for any of the promises in `promise_Images1` and `promise_Images2` because it won't see them, it'll just resolve its promise almost immediately with an array of those arrays.